# SSIS package intermittently failing when connecting to azure sql database

Tags: sql-server, ssis, azure-sql-database

I have an SSIS package, running in SQL Server on an Azure VM.
The SSIS package is connecting to a sql server database and getting some data.

When the source sql database is on our network, the query takes less than a second and there is never an issue.

Since the vendor moved the database to their Azure tenant, we are experiencing intermittent failures with the error:

> An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Driver 19 for SQL Server"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Client unable to establish connection".
> An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Driver 19 for SQL Server"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Client unable to establish connection because an error was encountered during handshakes before login. Common causes include client attempting to connect to an unsupported version of SQL Server, server too busy to accept new connections or a resource limitation (memory or maximum allowed connections) on the server.".

The issue is, the problem is intermittent, so the package succeeds 7 times out of 10.
The vendor says

- there are no deadlocks
- There are very few concurrent sessions at any given time
- They are seeing no failed connections or user errors in their logs

The fact that it succeeds 70% of the time indicates configuration is correct.
Can anyone advise what is the next step to take to try and find out why it is intermittently failing?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that they have a serverless environment and the 70% are when the server is hot from someone else and the failures are your team having to wait for it to spin up? If so, I'd either have the job set to retry after 15-30 seconds in the event of a failure or create a precursor package that does nothing but test whether the connection works. Have that scheduled 1 minute before the "real" package fires and see whether that fixes things.

Finally, there's something with the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient driver that has retry logic built in. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sql/configurable-retry-logic-for-microsoft-data-sqlclient/  You might check your version of the ole/ado driver and see if they've backported a similar feature.